# Play framework java backend with react front end doesnt return proper http response

Tags: java, reactjs, playframework, cors, sbt

Below has my application.conf file. And note that the reason, there are several lines is, I have tried several combinations to fix the issue. But could not find any fix.

**Fetch API call in React front end**

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000/items', {
        method: 'GET'
}).then(
    response => response.json()
).then(
    data => {
        console.log(data);
    }
).catch(
    error => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('errr');
    }
);
```

**Application.conf file**

```
play.filters.hosts {
   allowed = ["."]
}
play.filters.disabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
play.filters.disabled += play.filters.cors.CORSFilter
play.filters.disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://my.img.cdn.com"
# disable the built in filters
# play.http.filters = play.api.http.NoHttpFilters
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
play.filters.cors {
  # allow all paths
  pathPrefixes = ["/"]
  # allow all origins (You can specify if you want)
  allowedOrigins = null
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  # allow all headers
  allowedHttpHeaders = ["Accept", "Content-Type"]
```

Below image shows the options request which react front end requests.

[image: Options request which react front end requests]

Also below are the errors and warnings in the console.

[image: CORS]

Then checked with removing headers in http request. Then Got 200 by sending a GET request in the network tab. But thrown an exception in the fetch api call
[image: Without headers]

So it should be a cors issue in the play API it seems. But could not figure it out by doing different changes in application config.

Comment: why is the CORS filter both in the enabled & disabled lists in your configuration?

Comment: It's just for a test by doing. However, the issue is fixed and thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue and below will be the answer.

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:9000"]
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
  preflightMaxAge = 3 days
}
```

Hope this will be helpful for anyone.